# How to make 4k happen on mbpr 13 with U28D590D?

Tags: macos, display, 4k-resolution

So I'm trying to make U28D590D 4K monitor work with MacBook retina (13" Late 2013). So far I was able to make 30Hz over HDMI, but I'd like to get 60Hz via mDP.

It looks like people can do it using MacBooks with discrete graphics, but in my case I have integrated.

**What I've tried so far:**

Connecting via HDMI. Got 4k@30Hz, not good enough
Using mix of HDMI and mDP -> DP, PIB mode on the screen. Problem is one gets wrong colors & resolution, and I couldn't fix it.
SwitchResX. Doesn't allow me to save 4k, says "Not Activated - Invalid?"
I'm running Yosemite Beta if it makes any difference. Does any one know how to make it happen?

Comment: Everymac says those machines can only get 2k [2560x1440] so I'm surprised you even managed 4k at 30Hz, let alone 60. http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-13-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html

Comment: I've attached 2 1920x1080 monitors. So I have 2560x1440 + 1920x1080 + 1920x1080 working... 60Hz... I guess there is no hardware problem for 3840x2160, just software...

Comment: Which HDMI version does your macbook have? And which displayport version? The version of those limit the bandwidth. UNless you have HDMI 2.0 (not likely given the date of posting no HDMI output is going to so 4K at 60Hz. And if the source does not provide it no conversion will help either.